# Target second element and every third sibling that comes after

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a grid where I want to target the 2nd item in the grid and then every 3rd item after this.

In terms of hard coded CSS it looks like this:

```
.archive-article:nth-child(2),
.archive-article:nth-child(5),
.archive-article:nth-child(8), 
.archive-article:nth-child(11) {
   top: 2rem;
}
```

How would I do that with one CSS proprety? I've tried `.archive-article:nth-child(2n + 3)`, but that doesn't work.

Is it possible to actually do this with one property/value?

Any help or advice greatly appreciated

Comment: every third item --> `3n` so `3n + 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target every third sibling (`3n`) starting after the second sibling (`2`).

```css
section:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>1</section>
  <section>2</section>
  <section>3</section>
  <section>4</section>
  <section>5</section>
  <section>6</section>
  <section>7</section>
  <section>8</section>
  <section>9</section>
  <section>10</section>
  <section>11</section>
  <section>12</section>
  <section>13</section>
  <section>14</section>
</article>
```